# INSERT OR IGNORE INTO doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, insert

I have a table created as:

```
create table association (_id integer unique primary key autoincrement , id_rules integer, id_places integer)";
```

To avoid replication of entry, I use the statement INSERT OR IGNOR, but it doesn't work. For example,
value (id_rules , id_places) = ("11","1") alredy in table, but using:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO association (id_rules , id_places) VALUES ("11","1")
```

a new row is created.
Please, do anyone Know hwere is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INSERT OR IGNORE will ignore any rows that would violate a UNIQUE constraint.

The only such constraint is on the `_id` column, which you did not specify.

If you want to prevent duplicates in those two columns, you have to add a constraint for them to the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE association (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    id_rules INTEGER,
    id_places INTEGER,
    UNIQUE (id_rules, id_places)
);
```